# Infinity as essential singularity of $\dfrac{1}{e^{z}-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I have a problem, I know that the function $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{e^{z}-1}$ has a simple pole at $z=2i\pi k$ with $k\in \mathbb Z$, now for the behavior at infinity, we see if $f(\dfrac{1}{z})$ is holomorphic at $0$, in this case it is not analytic at zero. At the time of doing the Laurent series I get:

$\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k!z^{k}}}$

Now, $Res_\infty f(z)=Res_0 \dfrac{1}{z^2}f(\dfrac{1}{z})$ and with what we would have to $Res_\infty f(z)=1$

Am I correct or is there an error? first of all, Thanks

Comment: Infinity is not an isolated  singularity so not clear what Laurent series means here

Comment: Amm, I don't know if I understand, to find out if f is holomorphic at infinity what I do is see if f (1 / z) is holomorphic at 0 and clearly this function is not holomorphic at 0. Now, how do I classify that singularity?

Comment: Since there are poles at $2k\pi$ which have infinity  as limit point, it follows that infinity is not an isolated singularity, so there is no laurent series there; not sure if there is a specific name for such a singularity beyond limit of poles, while usually  essential  singularity is assumed isolated

Comment: I think I understand;  then for example the function $\dfrac{1+e^{z}}{z^{4}}$ If it has essential singularity in infinity since what does not happen in the example that is given?

Comment: Yes - this last function has a pole at zero and essential singularity  at infinity so it has a Laurent series, residue etc there

Comment: Correct, thanks you!